# Is there any way to write a curved arrow?

Tags: symbols, engineering, arrow-curve

I'd like to write a curved arrow along a line, like this one.
How can I write it?[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: It's not clear what you want. There are so many ways to draw arrows. Can you show us the context? What is it supposed to mean? I suggest you edit your question to add a complete ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that has a straight arrow where you want the curved one so we can understand your request.

Comment: There is `\rcurvearrowup` from the MnSymbol package.

Answer (score 5):

There exist many ways to draw arrows. For example directly by the `\pdfliteral` primitive:

```
x%
\leavevmode\hbox to6pt{%
   \pdfliteral{q 1 J .35 0 0 .35 -2 -2 cm
      10 0 m 20 10 20 20 10 30 c S 10 30 m 13 20 l 19 24 l h B Q}\hss}

\bye
```

Comment: If I can trust [the source](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TeX_primitives_listed_by_TeX_engine), this only works when one uses **pdflatex** engine to compile a document.

Comment: Or `pdftex`. Or `luatex` when `\def \pdfliteral {\pdfextension literal}` or `xetex` when `\def\pdfliteral#1{\special{pdf:literal #1}}`.

Comment: Would you like to explain anything about what's going on in the code block?

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5);%
% #1 : options for drawing
% #2 : center of arc
% #3 : start angle for arc
% #4 : end angle for arc
% #5 : radius of arc
{

    \draw[#1]([shift=(#3:#5)]#2) arc (#3:#4:#5);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!20] (0,0) grid (3,3);% comment if not needed
    \draw (1,1)--(2,2);% comment if not needed
    \draw (1,2)--(2,1);% comment if not needed
    \centerarc[cyan,line width=1pt,-latex](1,1.5)(-26.565:26.565:1.118cm);
\end{tikzpicture}   
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

More help for the code from this picture:

[image]

**EDIT**:
Other examples. Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5);%
% #1 : options for drawing
% #2 : center of arc
% #3 : start angle for arc
% #4 : end angle for arc
% #5 : radius of arc
{

    \draw[#1]([shift=(#3:#5)]#2) arc (#3:#4:#5);
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!20] (0,0) grid (3,3);% comment if not needed
    %\draw (1,1)--(2,2);% comment if not needed
    %\draw (1,2)--(2,1);% comment if not needed
    \filldraw[cyan] (1,1.5) circle(1pt);
    \draw[cyan,dotted] (2,2)--(1,1.5)--(2,1);
    \centerarc[cyan,line width=1pt,-latex](1,1.5)(-26.565:26.565:1.118cm);
    \filldraw[magenta] (0,1) circle(1pt);
    \draw[magenta,dotted] (1,0)--(0,1)--(1,2);
    \centerarc[magenta,line width=1pt,-latex](0,1)(-45:45:1.412);
    \filldraw[green] (1,0) circle(1pt);
    \draw[green,dotted] (3,1)--(1,0)--(0,2);
    \centerarc[green,line width=1pt,-latex](1,0)(26.565:116.565:2.236);
\end{tikzpicture}   
    
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]